# Flutter editor shows an error when I try to add an item to list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a list in flutter then add items to it . But the problem is I'm facing an error in the editor (Android Studio) . It says "Invalid constructor name" .

Here's my code format :

```
List<String > list = new List<String>();
  list.add(" ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that you are trying to write a method call in the class body. You should add items to the list in the body of the appropriate method. Only constructor calls are allowed in the class body.

```dart
class Wrong {
  List<String > list = new List<String>();
  list.add(""); // error: Invalid constructor name
}

class Ok {
  List<String > list = new List<String>();
  initState() {
    list.add("");
  }
}
```

Comment: @CopsOnRoad dart compiler takes a method `add` as a constructor.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad explanation added to answer

Comment: Got it, didn't know that error was actually named "Invalid constructor name". Anyways +1